# Intuition for gcd(a,b)

Tags: number-theory

Is there an intuitive way to understand the fact that, for $gcd(a,b)$, $a<b$, $b/gcd(a,b)$ is the number you need to multiply $a$ with to get a multiple of $b$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you divide $b$ by $\gcd(a,b)$ you are removing the factors $b$ has in common with $a$, and when you multiply by $a$ again you are putting them all back so the result is a multiple of $b$.  Also this number $\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}$ is minimal (excluding $0$) since if you divide $b$ by anything extra you won't get those factors back when multiplying by $a$.

Comment: Thank you! Other reply is great too but yours is intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

So, if $a < b$ we are inspecting $\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}$.

We want to understand why this fraction multiplied with $a$ gives a multiple of $b$.

Well, $\gcd(a,b)$ is a divisor of $a$, right? That means $\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)} = k$ for some integer $k$.

So, $a(\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}) = (\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)})b = kb = $ a multiple of $b$.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a scaled version of Euclid's Lemma (EL), viz. $ $ if $\, d = (a,b)\,$ then

$\ \ b\mid na \iff  \color{#c00}{b/d}\mid n\,\color{#c00}{a/d} \iff  b/d\mid n,\ $ by EL and $\ (\color{#c00}{a/d,b/d})=(a,b)/d = 1.$